# Automatic provisioning for Xamarin.iOS does not work

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, fastlane

I am trying to use automatic provisioning within VS on Mac.
Therefore I opened info.plist and switched to automatic provisioning.
I also have my Enterprise account all set up.
I get the following log:

```
Resolving certificate...
Fetching valid and locally installed signing identities...
Syncing certificates for "TEAMNAME" team...
Saving iOS Development certificates...
Syncing App IDs for "TEAMNAME" team...
Creating a new wildcard App ID...
Creating new App ID named VS Wildcard...

Automatic Provisioning failed: An App ID with Identifier '*' is not available. 
Please enter a different string.
```

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: What do you have set for the Bundle Identifier in your Info.plist file? Might also be worth looking over this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos#wildcard-app-ids

Comment: Bundleidentifier is set to de.companyname.appname

Answer (score 0):

Also see this [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/143915/automatic-provisioning-failed-an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available): https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/143915/automatic-provisioning-failed-an-app-id-with-identifier-is-not-available

This seems to suggest that you may already have a Wildcard App ID in Apple's developer portal. If so, log in there and delete any App IDs that use a wildcard "*"

Comment: That assumption is correct, there are already some wildcard App IDs. However I would like to not use "\*" as my ID. Is there a way, to use something more civil like de.companyname.* ? I cannot just delete the other wildcard IDs since other devs created them and probably need them. :-(

Comment: I think the issue is only with an App ID that has just `*` rather than something like  `com.company.*` Can you see if there is an App ID with just `*` as the bundle ID and check if anyone is using it, and if so, can they make a new one with something like `com.company.*`? Or use an existing `com.company.*` app ID?